# Want to get State Name from zip code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am making an iphone application which has a zip code field. When the user enter the zip code  I want to get the state name from zip code is it possible can any one suggest me.

Comment: I place my bet to google api :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi finally i have done with the help of google api.Also after pulling my hair for a long time a got a solution to it.

```
str_StateName = @"";
    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"United States,%@,%@",txt_City.text,txt_ZipCode.text];
    NSString *urlString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true", 
                            [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString1] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];

    //NSArray *names = [listItems valueForKeyPath:@"long_name"];
    for (i = 0; i < [listItems count]; i++)
    {
        if ([[listItems objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"administrative_area_level_1"])
        {
        NSLog(@"[listItems objectAtIndex:%d] %@",i,[listItems objectAtIndex:i-8]);
            str_StateName  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listItems objectAtIndex:i-8]];
        }
    }
    if([str_StateName isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        alertView    = [[ UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Please enter correct zip code and city." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Yahoo's API like :

```
 http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=77048&appid=0
```

> where q = zipCode

Comment: I am using google Api for it so how can we extract state name from that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Geocoding API for that like this

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=77048&sensor=true

where address is your zipcode.You can see [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for Geocoding API.